# How assign const reference to pointer within function in C++?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I had a function

```
void assign(std::vector<std::vector<double>> avg, int k) {
    double* ptr=&avg[k-1][0]
    //other stuff, but above is only line involving "avg" variable
}
```

But the function was running slower than I wanted because I passed by value instead of reference. If I tried the below:

```
void assign(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& avg, int k) {
    double* ptr=&avg[k-1][0]
    //other stuff
}
```

Then I get the error `cannot convert from const_Ty * to double*`. How can I have the function pass `avg` by reference?

Comment: Remove `const` in `const std::vector<std::vector<double>>&`? Note that any modifications to `avg` will then be visible outside of `assign` though.

Comment: is that the only way? I was hoping I could keep the `const` to ensure `avg`'s values don't change

Comment: Then use `double const* ptr = &avg[k-1][0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify a `const` object either directly or indirectly. This includes its assignment to objects that can be modified (non-const).

There are 2 options: either make `ptr` const, or remove the constness of the argument. The former would make the pointer read only (which might be fine or not), while the later would open the reference to changes (which is not really a good thing in most of the cases).

You can also consider if you really need to have that pointer.